# Meteor Blaze order sub-documents by sub-document property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, meteor, reactive-programming

Profile:

```
_id: Pe0t3K8GG8,
videos: [
   {id:'HdaZ8rDAmy', url:'VIDURL', rank: 2},
   {id:'22vZ8mj9my', url:'VIDURL2', rank: 0},
   {id:'8hyTlk8H^6', url:'VIDURL3', rank: 1},
]
```

The profile is displayed together with the list of videos. I have a Drag & Drop which updates the videos rank using a Server Method.

1) the database updates correctly on **Drop**.

2) To sort the videos Array - I declare a helper on the **Profile Template** and **SORT** the **videos** array based on a **custom comparison function**.

```
Template.Profile.helpers({
    'videosSorted': function(){
        let videos = (this.videos);
        let videosSorted = videos.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseFloat(a.rank) - parseFloat(b.rank);
    });
    return videosSorted;
  }
});
```

## Problem:

A) In Blaze the `{{#each videosSorted}}` does not reactively update. 
If I F5 refresh then i can see the new order.

*I think the issue is because I am providing **videosSorted** which does not update on changes to the document in the db.*

How can I make **videosSorted** reactive?

## Update:

**All related code:** 
Iron Router Controller - I subscribe and set the data context for the  layout

```
ProfileController = RouteController.extend({
 subscriptions: function() {
    this.subscribe('profile',this.params.slug).wait();
  },
  data: function () {
     //getting the data from the subscribed collection
     return Profiles.findOne({'slug':this.params.slug});
  },
})
```

**Publication:**

```
Meteor.publish('profile', function (slug) {
  const profile = Profiles.find({"slug":slug});
  if(profile){
    return profile;
  }
  this.ready();
});
```

**The Profile HTML template:**

```
<template name="Profile">
     <ul  class="sortlist">
        {{#each videosSorted}}
            {{> Video}}
        {{/each}}
     </ul>
</template>
```

I am using  **mrt:jquery-ui** - sortable function

```
Template.Profile.onRendered(function () {
  thisTemplate = this;

  this.$('.sortlist').sortable({
    stop: function(e, ui) {

      el = ui.item.get(0);
      before = ui.item.prev().get(0);
      after = ui.item.next().get(0);

      if(!before) {
        newRank = Blaze.getData(after).rank - 1
      } else if(!after) {
        newRank = Blaze.getData(before).rank + 1
      }
      else {
        newRank = (Blaze.getData(after).rank +
          Blaze.getData(before).rank) / 2
      }

      let queryData = {
          _id: thisTemplate.data._id,    //the id of the profile record
          videos_objId: Blaze.getData(el).objId,    //the id of the sub document to update
          new_rank: newRank  //the new rank to give it
      };

      //Update the sub document using a server side call for validation + security  
      Meteor.call("updateVideoPosition", queryData, function (error, result) {
          if(!result){
            console.log("Not updated");
          }
          else{
            console.log("successfully updated Individual's Video Position")
          }
      });
   }
 })
});
```

And finally the Meteor method that does the updating

```
'updateVideoPosition': function (queryData){
    let result = Individuals.update(
      {_id: queryData._id, 'videos.objId': queryData.videos_objId },
      { $set:{ 'videos.$.rank' : queryData.new_rank } }
    )
    return result;
  }
```

### **Note :**

As i mentioned - the database updates correctly - and if i have an Incognito window open to the same page - i see the videos reactivly (magically !)  switch to the new order.

## The schema

```
const ProfileSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  name:{
    type: String,
  }
  videos: {
    type: [Object],
    optional:true,
  },
  'videos.$.url':{
    type:String,
  },
  'videos.$.rank':{
    type:Number,
    decimal:true,
    optional:true,
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden",
    }
  },
  'videos.$.subCollectionName':{
    type:String,
    optional:true,
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden",
    }
  },
  'videos.$.objId':{
    type:String,
    optional:true,
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden",
    }
  } 
});
```

Comment: Does it happen to work if you do `let videos = this.videos.slice()`?

Comment: How is your collection defined?

Comment: All helpers are reactive and depend on `currentData()`. So, your helper should work reactively. Probably you lost reactiveness on previous template level. Can you post all js/html code related to video's document?

Comment: @Tdm  I habe updated the question, below the  **Update** header

Comment: @DavidWeldon using slice() made no difference

Comment: @L4zl0w - my collection is defined in Simple-Schema. I have added the schema to the question

Comment: **Update**  - Inside the `Video` template I am displaying `{{this.rank}}` - and I can see the actual rank number does update.  

It is the #Each that is not re-rendering the order of the list.

Comment: Update 2 - I can also see that when I drag & drop a video - the videosSorted helper runs again - and the **return** is the correct new order. So it really seems that it is the #Each that has lost reactivity

Comment: Ok. Diagnosis. The videosSorted helper is being called before the asynchrous update to mongo.  How can I call that helper to run manually after the method returns.

Comment: Hmm but that should be reactive. I can think of two ways. One, using a reactive variable as a parameter when you subscribe. Two, using observeChange in your publication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with really crude solution, but I don't see other options right now. The simplest solution I can think of is to rerender template manually:

```
Template.Profile.onRendered(function () {
  var self = this;
  var renderedListView;
  this.autorun(function () {
    var data = Template.currentData(); // depend on tmeplate data
    //rerender video list manually
    if (renderedListView) {
      Blaze.remove(renderedListView);
    }
    if (data) {
      renderedListView = Blaze.renderWithData(Template.VideoList, data, self.$('.videos-container')[0]);
    }
  });
});
Template.VideoList.onRendered(function () {
  var tmpl = this;
  tmpl.$('.sortlist').sortable({
    stop: function (e, ui) {
      var el = ui.item.get(0);
      var before = ui.item.prev().get(0);
      var after = ui.item.next().get(0);
      var newRank;
      if (!before) {
        newRank = Blaze.getData(after).rank - 1
      } else if (!after) {
        newRank = Blaze.getData(before).rank + 1
      }
      else {
        newRank = (Blaze.getData(after).rank +
          Blaze.getData(before).rank) / 2
      }
      let queryData = {
        _id: tmpl.data._id,    //the id of the profile record
        videos_objId: Blaze.getData(el).objId,    //the id of the sub document to update
        new_rank: newRank  //the new rank to give it
      };
      //Update the sub document using a server side call for validation + security
      Meteor.call("updateVideoPosition", queryData, function (error, result) {
        if (!result) {
          console.log("Not updated");
        }
        else {
          console.log("successfully updated Individual's Video Position")
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
Template.VideoList.helpers({
  videosSorted: function () {
    return this.videos.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.rank - b.rank;
    });
  }
});
```

And HTML:

```
<template name="Profile">
  <div class="videos-container"></div>
</template>

<template name="VideoList">
  <ul class="sortlist">
    {{#each videosSorted}}
      <li>{{url}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

Reativeness was lost in your case because of JQuery UI Sortable. It doesn't know anything about Meteor's reactiveness and simply blocks template rerendering.

Probably you should consider using something more adopted for Meteor like [this](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/tree/master/meteor) (I am not sure it fits your needs).